# How to append dictionaries to a list without overwriting data

Tags: python

I'm having a bit of trouble with a function I'm trying to write. What it is supposed to do is 1) go to a particular URL and get a list of financial sectors stored in a particular div; 2) visit each sector's respective page and get 3 particular pieces of information from there; 3) put the gathered collection into a dictionary; and 4) append that dictionary to another dictionary.

The desired output is a dictionary containing a list of dictionaries for all the sectors.

Here is my function:

```
def fsr():
    fidelity_sector_report = dict()
    url = "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/goto/markets_sectors/landing.jhtml"
    
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    # scrape the url page and locate links for each sector
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if not response.status_code == 200:
            return 'Main page error'
        page = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
        
        sectors = page.find_all('a',class_="heading1")
        for sector in sectors:
            link = 'https://eresearch.fidelity.com/' + sector['href']
            name = sector.text
            sect = dict()
            lst = []
            
            # scrape target pages for required information
            try:
                details = requests.get(link)
                if not details.status_code == 200:
                    return 'Details page error'
                details_soup = BeautifulSoup(details.content,'lxml')
                
                fundamentals = details_soup.find('div',class_='sec-fundamentals')
                values = dict()
                
                #locate required values by addressing <tr> text and put them in a dictionary
                values['Enterprise Value'] = fundamentals.select_one('th:contains("Enterprise Value") + td').text.strip()
                values['Return on Equity (TTM)'] = fundamentals.select_one('th:contains("Return on Equity (TTM)") + td').text.strip()
                values['Dividend Yield'] = fundamentals.select_one('th:contains("Dividend Yield") + td').text.strip()
                
                #add values to the sector dictionary
                sect[name] = values
                
                # add the dictionary to the list
                lst.append(dict(sect))
                
                # for a dictionary using the list
                fidelity_sector_report['results'] = lst
            except:
                return 'Something is wrong with details request'
            
        return fidelity_sector_report
    except:
        return "Something is horribly wrong"
```

AS far as I can tell, it performs the main taks wonderfully, and the problem appears at the stage of appending a formed dictionary to a list - instead of adding new piece, it gets overwritten completely. I figured that out by putting `print(lst)` right after the `fidelity_sector_report['results'] = lst` line.

What should I change so that list (and, correspondingly, dictionary) gets formed as planned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the `lst=[]` outside of the sectors loop.
Your problem appears since for each sector, you reset `lst` and you append the current sector data to an empty list.

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right. Worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The following code causes the value of `fidelity_sector_report['results']` to be replaced with `lst`.

```
fidelity_sector_report['results'] = lst
```

I presume you would want to access the respective values using a key, you can add the following line below `fidelity_sector_report = dict()` to initialize a dictionary:

```
fidelity_sector_report['results'] = {}
```

Then, create a key for each sector using the sector name and set the value with your `values` dictionary by replacing `fidelity_sector_report['results'] = lst` with:

```
fidelity_sector_report['results'][name] = dict(values)
```

You can access the data by using the relevant keys, i.e `fidelity_sector_report['results']['Financials']['Dividend Yield']` for the dividend yield of the financials sector.

Comment: oh, man, I think you're overcomplicating things a bit. Thanks for the contribution, though